# How to change param in url before ? on click?

Tags: angular

I have multiple tabs and on load i have this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/local/evident/1248/161/1?procesId=12
```

Changing tabs on using class show and hide. It use `index` that goes from 0 to 10. What i need is when user click on some tab to find this number before `?` and change it because it change tab, so when i refresh page to stay on that tab that is clicked. Any suggestion how can i do that. I have index number but i need to pass it in `url` to change that number before `?procesId`, in my case that number is 1.

Im using this method to set active index:

```
activate(index: any) {

        this.active = index;
        this.confing[this.active]['disabled'] = false
        this.selected = this.confing[this.active];

    }
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit more confusing

Comment: Can you post the `Config` file

Comment: Config file is type of flowTab that have name and disabled (true,false)

Comment: Use router.navigation() with changed new url and for the options: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change url on tab click by doing something like the following:

```
router.navigateByUrl(myApiUrl+"/"+tabId+"?"+itemId, { skipLocationChange: true });
```

and pay attention to include necessary "/","=","?", etc